# Moore Penrose pseudoinverse of this singular matrix arising in machine learning

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, inverse

In machine learning, we often come across "centering matrices" of the form:

$H_n := I_n - \frac{1}{n}1_n 1_n^{T}$, where $1_n:=[1,1,...1]^{T}$ is the column vector of all one's. I'd like to calculate (**not numerically calculate, but have an explicit formula or expression for**) the [Moore Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $H_n$. Helps appreciated!!

Comment: Surely $H_n^{\dagger} = H_n$?

Comment: Verify by the definition that any Hermitian ($H^*=H$) idempotent ($H^2=H$) matrix is its own MP pseudoinverse.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you, also thanks to Copper.hat for the answer. What is the operator norm of $H_n$ though?

Comment: $H_n$ is the orthogonal projection. The operator norm is $1$ (the same as the operator norm of $\Lambda$ in the answer).

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you for your input - I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $e=(1,...,1)^T$, and let $v_2,...,v_n$ be an orthonormal basis for $\{e\}^\bot$. Then
with $v_1 = {1 \over \sqrt{n}} e$, we have
$H_nv_1 = 0$ and $H_n v_k = v_k$ for $k > 1$. Let $V$ be the matrix whose columns are $v_k$,
then $H_n = V \Lambda V^T$, where $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(0,1,\cdots,1)$.

It follows from the SVD that $H_n^\dagger = V \Lambda^\dagger V^T = V \Lambda V^T = H_n$.

Comment: Thank you for the detail. What is the operator norm of $H_n$ though?

Comment: The above gives the SVD so it is one.

Comment: Thank you for replying!